# tcp ip connection to open port in a docker container within macvlan network

Tags: docker, docker-network, macvlan

I'm starting up a container within a `macvlan` driver powered docker network, this is the relevant bit of my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  tws:
    build: ./ib-docker
    image: ibconnect
    container_name: ibconnect
    ports:
      - "4001:4001"
      - "4003:4003"
      - "5901:5901"
    networks: 
      - connect

networks: 
  connect: 
    driver: macvlan
```

when the driver was `bridge` I could just `nc localhost 4001` to access my container and establish a connection, now with the macvlan this seem not to be working any more, and I'm not sure how to access it.

any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: macvlan is an overlay network that assigns an IP address to your container. You can't use localhost to access that container, you would hit the assigned IP address. You can remove the port mapping, since all ports are accessible on the assigned IP and nothing needs to be forwarded to the host.